# Dojo DataGrid - Getting data store item from formatter?

Tags: datagrid, dojo

From what I've seen, the formatter function in Dojo DataGrid is given the following arguments: cell value, cell row number, and the cell object itself. Can you suggest how to obtain data store item to which this cell refers, given these arguments? Or if you can suggest an alternative way, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. The grid has a method called getItem(), which accepts row number as argument.